# Stop jquery animation

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate, diagonal

I am having a problem with jquery animation. My code is as follows:

```
 if((valorscrollpx >= 800) && (valorscrollpx <= 1700))
  {
      $('#loquehacebien').fadeIn(600);
      $('#loquehacebien_estrella').animate({left: '-=500', top: '+=80'}, 1800);
  }
  else
  {
    $('#loquehacebien').fadeOut(600);
  }
```

The problem is that I don't know how to stop this animation! 
When the scroll reaches 800 px animation begins and ends, but every time I move the scroll animation starts again from the point it was.
What can i do?. I just need the animation begins and ends 1 time alone.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need to animate the star just one time, you can use a flag like that :

put

```
var flag = false;
```

outside `$(window).scroll(...);`

and replace your code by

```
if((valorscrollpx >= 800) && (valorscrollpx <= 1700) && !flag)   {
       $('#loquehacebien').fadeIn(600);       
       $('#loquehacebien_estrella').animate({left: '-=500', top: '+=80'}, 1800);
       flag = true;   
}   else   {     
       $('#loquehacebien').fadeOut(600);   
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!. 
I still don't understand what to do. Please see this link: http://www.adminvps.com.ar/trabajos/test/ 

If you advance to scroll the star moves and doesn't stop. I need this to stop. How I do this?

Comment: if you need to animate the star just one time, you can use a flag like that :
`var flag = false;
if((valorscrollpx >= 800) && (valorscrollpx <= 1700) && !flag)
  {
      $('#loquehacebien').fadeIn(600);
      $('#loquehacebien_estrella').animate({left: '-=500', top: '+=80'}, 1800);
      flag = true;
  }
  else
  {
    $('#loquehacebien').fadeOut(600);
  }`
if it's you are looking for, I'll replace my answer by this comment

Comment: just put the `var flag = false;` outside `$(window).scroll(...);`

Comment: It works perfect!, Thank you very much!!!! 
One last question: If I need that when the scroll pass the 1700px $('#loquehacebien_estrella') will cheer up (to clear), what can I do?.
Summary, when the scroll is in position between 800px and 1700px $('#loquehacebien_estrella') appears, else disappears.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your last question.
but you can try :
$('#loquehacebien_estrella').show(); in your first condition and 
$('#loquehacebien_estrella').hide(); in your second.
If my answers are ok for you, can you please mark as green ? ;)

Comment: Yes, of course I'll mark green, you helped me a lot!. If i mark as green now, you can just help me with this last question?. 
I need that  $('#loquehacebien_estrella') back to top when the scroll isn't between 800 and 1700px. In the else I need to do the opposite.

Comment: come on it's not the way this communitary website works. i gave you your answer you need to work a little my friend. But you can do this maybe `$("loquehacebien_estrella").css("top", "0px")` I wont do all the code, you will have to search a little but using position absolute you can trick the desired effect